# When I installed the React observer, the error is coming saying that the file "Error: Failed to read source code from "

Tags: next.js, node-modules

I am making my portfolio using the Next js 14 and the tailwind css. I was making the timeline to show my projects. In Next js 14 it was not displaying anything so I made the animate = false. It started to display the timeline but it was not showing the popup animation. So I decided to use the react observer for observing when the timeline fragment appears then I will show the animation.
Now when i installed the react observer it is giving the following as shown in the screen shot. So please help me with this error...

I am expecting that this error resolves and the react observer works properly, without any error...